# How to disable an input field using js

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried several ways to disable the input field but it isn't working here is the code:

```
    function checkAnswers(){
        const answerField1 = document.getElementById('answer-field1');
        const submitButton = document.getElementById('submit-button')
        if (answerField1.value == ...){
            answerField1.disabled = true;
            submitButton.disabled = 'disabled';
            answerField1.style.backgroundColor = '#31CD16';
            checkmark.style.display = 'block';
            score ++;
            scoreElement.textContent = score.toString();
        }else{
            answerField1.style.backgroundColor = '#A90305';`
            crossmark.style.display = 'block';
            correctAnswer.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
```

I have tried to use the disable : 'disabled'; and the answerField1.disable = true; none worked

Comment: Please provide the HTML for a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Your `if` statement also seems a bit weird `answerField1.value == ...`

Comment: When checkAnswers function is called exactly. Please describe the problem

Comment: You have a trailing **\`** here:  `answerField1.style.backgroundColor = '#A90305';\``

Answer (score -2):

here a example on disabled a button and input field. In your case check your
IF condition may there is a problem or provide the HTML

```html
 <input type="text" id="answer-field1" value="test" >
    <button type="submit" id="submit-button" > Submit </button>
    
    <button type="button" onclick="checkAnswers()" > Disabled</button>
    
    <script>
      function checkAnswers(){
      const answerField1 = document.getElementById('answer-field1');
      const submitButton = document.getElementById('submit-button')
         answerField1.disabled = true;
        submitButton.disabled = 'disabled';
      
    }
    </script>
```